# creating an abstract type as a wrapper for different functions

Tags: types, julia

I'm trying to create an `abstract type` that is a superclass (called `Kernel`) several different of functions, each a subclass of `Kernel` --i.e.

```
abstract type Kernel end

struct ExponentialKernel <: Kernel
    ExponentialKernel(rate::Number, x::Number) = exp(-1*rate*x)
end


struct GaussianKernel <: Kernel
    GaussianKernel(sigma::Number, x::Number) = (1.0/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))) * exp((-1*x^2)/(2*sigma^2)
end

...
```

and so on.

When I use what I have above, it works in the sense that when I call `ExpKernel(a,b)` I get the right value, but when I try to pass these kernel objects to a different constructor, like

```
mutable struct Model
    kernel::T where {T <: Kernel}    

    Model(kernel) = new(kernel) 
end
```

but when I try to call `Model(ExpKernel)` I get the error

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Type{ExpKernel} to an object of type Kernel
```

Is there something I'm missing about types here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
julia> mutable struct Model
           kernel::DataType

           Model(k::Type{<:Kernel}) =
               isconcretetype(k) ? new(k) : throw(ArgumentError("concrete type required"))
       end

julia> Model(GaussianKernel)
Model(GaussianKernel)

julia> Model(1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Model(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Model(::Type{var"#s1"} where var"#s1"<:Kernel) at REPL[4]:4
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1

julia> Model(Kernel)
ERROR: ArgumentError: concrete type required
Stacktrace:
 [1] Model(::Type{Kernel}) at .\REPL[4]:4
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[7]:1
```

Note however that this is not a typical design pattern in Julia - normally you would use https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects-1 pattern for such functionality.